# Hiding classes in a jar file

Tags: java, jar, factory-pattern, information-hiding, facade

Is it really impossible to hide some classes in a jar file?

I wanted not to allow direct instantiation of the classes to keep it more flexible. Only the factory (or a facade) should be visible of this jar.

Is there any other way than solve this problem than creating two projects?
(Two projects: the first one contains the classes (implementation) and the other one references to the first one and contains the factory; later only the second one will be referenced)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "hiding".  Jar files are just .zip files, so anyone can open them and see your class files inside them.

Comment: I just want to avoid that the classes can be used outside (by accident) for instantiation.

Comment: I do think you should trust the user of your classes and provide decent enough documentation to what to use and what not to. There's no way you can prevent all the mistakes developers using your jars can come up with anyway. One alternative of course is just to make your own constructors so complex no-one can understand them and will fall back naturally to the factory classes :D

Comment: Also I don't think there's point in adding this kind of flexibility until it really is used for something. And just for flexibility, maybe you could look into some Inversion of Control frameworks like Spring (or something more lightweight depending on your needs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will have either compiler failure or warning if your public factory method try to return something which is "hidden".

No, you can not hide a public class without reimplementing your own `ClassLoader` or using OSGi or anything similar.

What you can do is to separate interface api from the implementation, e.g. have one project which contains only the interfaces and another porject which contains the implmentations. However, you still cannot hide the implementation classes.

Comment: Thats what I meant by creating two projects. I think I will do that even if it it increases the number of projects.

Answer (score 5):

I'm understanding you're not looking to hide the actual classes, just prevent their construction outside a factory class. This I think can be quite easily achieved by using package private (default) visibility in the class constructors. The only limitation is that you'll need to have the classes and the factory in the same package so in a medium to large codebase things may get unnecessarily complex.

Comment: Oh actually, this way anyone can still call your constructors by creating their own factory classes and placing them in the same package.. Maybe it would be better to start with _why_ you want to hide these things?

Comment: You got it. But the limitation is exactly the problem. There are many classes and I really don't want to put all in one package.

Comment: @ Mikko: To your comment: That could be solved by sealing the package.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to make sure that users of your library are forced to use your factory to instantiate their objects rather than using the constructors themselves.

As I see it there are two possibilities, one of which is silly but usable in few, specific cases, and the other one is the most practical and probably most commonly used way of doing it.

1. You could make all your classes into
   [private inner classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) of the
   factory. This would work if you had
   one factory per class, but is hardly
   workable if you have a lot of
   different classes being managed
   through one factory.
2. You could use the `protected` access modifier to
   restrict access to your class
   constructors. **This is common
   practice** when using the [factory
   pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#Example).

Comment: The first one is - as you said - silly. The second one has the problem that the factory has to be in the same package.

Comment: @nrainer :) I've used it in cases when you have a factory for just one single class with many instantiation options, but other than in that specific case, it is not advisable.

Comment: I find this answer perfectly suiting my requirement when i want to hide the complete business logic of my library from the consuming application.

Answer (score 2):

[*Obfuscation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation) can help you *somehow*.

Comment: Seconded, even though it doesn't hide it.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer.
However, I think that is overkill for my requirement.

Answer (score 2):

With standard classloaders and plain old jar files, this is not possible. OSGi has this concept of making visible only some packages to another bundle(i.e. separation of public api and internal implementation).

If you are using eclipse, you may enforce such rules with [this](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t53736.html)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly when you say "not to allow direct instantiation of the classes to keep it more flexible", a properly executed facade pattern will handle this.

Restrict the constructors of all the classes you want to hide to package scope. Open the facade class to public scope.

http://mindprod.com/jgloss/packagescope.html

> "If you have a variable or method in
>   your class that you don’t want clients
>   of your class directly accessing,
>   don’t give it a public, protected or
>   private declaration. Due to an
>   oversight in the design of Java, you
>   can’t explicitly declare the default
>   “package” accessibility. Other members
>   of the package will be able to see it,
>   but classes outside the package that
>   inherit from yours, won’t. The
>   protected accessibility attribute
>   offers slightly more visibibily. A
>   protected method is visible to
>   inheriting classes, even not part of
>   the same package. A package scope
>   (default) method is not. That is the
>   only difference between protected and
>   package scope. "

Comment: Unfortunately then the facade has to be in the same package. As there are many classes, I don't want that.

Comment: I haven't experimented, but you should be able to put you're facade class in one package and have your implementing classes in children packages. That way the facade and implementing classes are all in the same package and you get the organization of having many packages.

Comment: As far as I know pck1.subPck1 has nothing to do with pck1. Therefore I don't think it will work. (The namespaces in C# would allow that. Anyway, if I used C# I would not have this problem because of the internal modifier which would solve my problem.)

Comment: +1 this seems to be the easiest way. just simply do 'String str;' instead of 'public/private/protected String str;'

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions to your question that don't involve keeping all classes in the same package.

The first is to use the Friend Accessor/[Friend Package](http://wiki.apidesign.org/wiki/APIDesignPatterns:FriendPackages) pattern described in (Practical API Design, Tulach 2008).

The second is to use OSGi.  There is an article [here](http://www.1biznow.com/2009/02/hide-private-parts-of-your-bundle.html) explaining how OSGi accomplishes this.

Related Questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872124/how-to-hide-the-internal-structure-of-a-java-api-to-the-rest-of-the-world/6154321#6154321), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759692/hiding-classes-in-a-jar-file), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647599/why-friend-directive-is-missing-in-java), and [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182278/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-the-c-friend-concept-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

You can do such magics with a custom class loader but:

- the correct separation will be available only in a project staffed with your class loader;
- it's really doubtful that the effort to create such loader is worthy.

In such situations I would do something similar to what we may see in the standard Java. E.g.you see `javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory` but somewhere you have `com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl`. It is perfectly compilable if you write:

```
new com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl()
```

though you will hardly do it :-) With a system property you may control the actual implementation that is being loaded. To me such approach is fine in many situations.

I hope I have understood your question correctly ;)

Cheers!