# Using Security manager to prevent public method access

Tags: java, security, securitymanager

I had once come across a post that said that we can use the `SecurityManager` to restrict certain classes from calling a `public` method of another class. How do we do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have at least linked to the answer, and then said more clearly, what you don't understand. [So, I will link for you to my answer to a similar question from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486797/how-to-prevent-public-methods-from-being-called-from-specific-classes/5490106#5490106).

If something still is not clear, comment on this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps they are thinking of hiding packages hierarchies from classes loaded by other class loaded through the `package.access` security property. See [Guidelines 1-1a](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html#1-1a) of the Secure Coding Guidelines for the Java Programming Language, Version 3.0. Other than that, if a class cannot see a `ClassLoader` (by any means!) then they will not be able to interact with classes of that class loader.