# Difference between non- final public static and non- final public instance fields in terms of security?

Tags: java, java-security

I am going through this link , [OBJ10-J. Do not use public static nonfinal fields](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/OBJ10-J.+Do+not+use+public+static+nonfinal+fields) and it says that ,

> Client code can trivially access public static fields because access
>   to such fields are not checked by a security manager.

what do they actually mean by that? i.e what do they mean by escaping from security manager?

If they simply meant it because field being **non-final** and `public` , then how come **non-final** , `public` instance fields different than their `static` counterparts? ( as far as code security is concerned )

I have been through this question and have not seen any mention in terms of security , [Why are static variables considered evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil)

`public` class's `public static` fields would be accessible from anywhere and so `public` instance fields too, so where is the difference? Why **non-final** `public` instance fields not a security issue but being `static` is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why non-final public instance fields not a security issue but being static is?

If you want to access an instance field you need the reference to that object instance. If you don't have a reference you can't access it.

So your code can control to which objects a refernce is passed. If malicious code tries to hijack one of your objects using reflection to get a reference you can install a security manager to prevent this.

On the other side a `public static` field can be accessed from everybody that has access to the class, because the `Class` object is accessible. So malicious code might only use

```
YourClass.PUBLIC_INSTANCE_FIELD = someValue;
```

or the reflection way

```
Class clazz = Class.forName("YourClass");
Field publicStaticField = clazz.getDeclaredField("PUBLIC_INSTANCE_FIELD");
publicStaticField.set(null, someValue);
```

Comment: so is there no way to apply access restrictions on `Class Object`? Eventually, that is an Object too but not kept in heap, right?

Comment: @SabirKhan I don't know what you mean with "apply access restrictions on Class Object".  Do you want to protect the main memory (RAM) from being hijacked?

Comment: What I meant to ask is , is class name in your example `YourClass` an instance of `java.lang.Class`? so if `YourClass` is simply a reference of type `java.lang.Class` then I can apply security manager on it too ( like suggested for heap objects ) or security manager can't be applied to **jvm** created `Class` Objects?

Comment: @SabirKhan Yes, `YourClass` is the class object and I think you can apply a security manager as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486797/how-to-prevent-public-methods-from-being-called-from-specific-classes

Answer (score 4):

That's because the case of non-static fields is already covered by [OBJ01-J. Limit accessibility of fields](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/OBJ01-J.+Limit+accessibility+of+fields)

`public` instance field are covered by OBJ01-J for slightly different reasons. For one, you need to have a reference to an instance before you can change public instance fields, while public static fields can be accessed directly at class level. But both are against the CERT rules.

Comment: so that sentence (that public instance fields escape security manager) applicable here too, right ? What I understand by that is `public` fields are intended to be accessed from anywhere and disabling **refelction** etc will not have any impact or there is no way to include these accesses in security manager.

Comment: @SabirKhan Yes that's correct, public fields cannot be controlled by a SecurityManager. Non-public fields that you normally cannot access can be accessed through reflection, but you can use the SecurityManager to disable or control access through reflection.