# Java SecurityManager - how to ensure a method is run only by another method?

Tags: java, security

I want B to be run only by the `private` method `A#getSensitiveData()` that uses or does some processing on sensitive data (example: cryptographic keys, national id, whatever).

```
public final class A{
    private transient final B sensitiveHolder; //set at Constructor
    public A(B sensitiveHolder){
        this.sensitiveHolder = sensitiveHolder;
    }
    private final byte[] getSensitiveData(){
        return sensitiveHolder.getSensitiveData();
    }
}

public final class B{
    private transient final byte[] sensitiveData;//encrypt and set at Constructor
    public final byte[] getSensitiveData(){
        //check if it is run by A#getSensitiveData(); if it is, decrypt by DEK and give plaintext.
    }
}
```

Please take into account that the code would be obfuscated, so please refrain from putting in any package names as `String`.

What must I write with `SecurityManager#checkPrivilege()` and `AccessController.doPrivileged()` before I can achieve such an effect?

EDIT: Obviously this is different because the so called "answer" does not contain any CODE. WORKING CODE is worth infinitely more than "oh, just do this and that".

Comment: For a working answer with code that solves the question of how `B.getSensitiveData` can check and limit who is calling it, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41420960/14955  It does not use a SecurityManager, though.

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this:

```
private boolean verify(final StackTraceElement e[]) {
    boolean doNext = false;
    for (final StackTraceElement s : e) {
        if (doNext && s.getClassName().equals("A") && s.getMethodName().equals("getSensitiveData"))
            return true;
        doNext = s.getMethodName().equals("getStackTrace");
    }
    return false;
}
```

And to call the method:

```
public final byte[] getSensitiveData(StackTraceElement e[]){
    if (verify(e)) {
        // Do something good
    }
}
```

In your `A` class call your `B` class like this:

```
return sensitiveHolder.getSensitiveData(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace());
```

I don't know if this is what you need or it is near that. You could play around the values in the `equals` section of the `if`. I got and modified the example from [this](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0420.html) site.

Answer (score 3):

If you're able to use JDK 9+, which introduces `StackWalker`, this sort of thing might work for you.  This technique seems to supersede use of `sun.reflect.Reflection#getCallerClass(int)`.  (I hope you weren't counting on a SecurityManager-related answer.)

```
package asdf;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Asdf {

  @Test
  public void what() {
    get();
  }

  void get() {
    StackWalker.StackFrame stackFrame =
        StackWalker.getInstance(EnumSet.of(StackWalker.Option.RETAIN_CLASS_REFERENCE))
            .walk(stream -> {
              List<StackWalker.StackFrame> stackFrames = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
              return stackFrames.get(1);
            });
    Assertions.assertEquals(Asdf.class, stackFrame.getDeclaringClass());
    Assertions.assertEquals("what", stackFrame.getMethodName());
    Assertions.assertEquals(0, stackFrame.getMethodType().parameterCount());

    // now do caller-sensitive stuff
  }
}
```