# How to prevent developers from use risky methods

Tags: java

I'm looking for a way to prevent developers from using some methods that are causing instability (Performance) issues for the site; for example, I have a method fetches the information from the database (e.g. `getData(String id)`), and another method fetches the information form the in-memory cache (e.g. `getCachedData(String id)`). The `getData(String id)` method is used in `getCachedData(String id)` if and only if we have a cache-miss. How can I prevent developers from using `getData(String id)` method? in other words, I need to force developers to use `getCachedData(String id)` always.

Please note that the access modifiers (private, protected, etc.), code design, or java docs are `not` really preventing developers. Do we have a final solution for this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent public methods from being called from specific classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486797/how-to-prevent-public-methods-from-being-called-from-specific-classes)

Comment: "access modifiers (**private**, protected, etc.), are not really preventing developers". How do they bypass it? Are they using reflection?!

Comment: Nope, these methods are distributed in different classes. The problem, there are many system architects worked on the same platform, everyone created his own utility to read from the cache, currently, I have 5 different implementations that do the same functionality (some of them w/ cache and others w/ no cache), cleaning up all of them will take an extremely long time.

Comment: @dyukha, they are able to change the code, as we have an API w/ no docs, the simplest approach is to look the SQL queries and see the closest method/implementation for it. The problem that we are not really able to review hundreds of line of code every day.

Comment: @AhmadAlMughrabi, even if you block the particular method. devs could just slap a raw query themselves. it can be mitigated with some automatic code-inspector as suggested below. but if someone creates a new libary, publish it to maven for instance. then use it. you wont know unless you review the code manually. its more like, need to educate the devs.

Comment: "**final** solution": eliminate the "risky methods". Also "5 different implementations that do the same functionality" is obviously not desired.... and, most important, as Bagus already commented: educate the devs!

Comment: @bagusTesa, I agree with you. I see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57655221/how-to-prevent-developers-from-use-risky-methods#comment101760790_57655308 is more relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Document the methods well, and explain which is preferable.
2. Write a custom annotation to produce a compilation warning.
3. Decorate the class, so `getData` would return `getCachedData`.

The interface is pretty unclear, there shouldn't be a method `getCachedData` at all. `getData` returns either the cached data or newly-fetched data.

Comment: Thanks, @Andrew - the problem, there are many system architects worked on the same platform, everyone created his own utility to read from the cache, currently, I have 5 different implementations that do the same functionality (some of them w/ cache and others w/ no cache), cleaning up all of them will take an extremely long time. I need a short-term solution that at least keep the production safe.

Comment: but how do the 5 implementations fetch the data? different sql implementation? or all of them call getData() at the end?

Comment: @AhmadAlMughrabi You can't really "force" someone to use a particular method if they have full access to the codebase and, thus, may change anything. A good tactic would be to introduce pull requests to the team and review them on the presence of the method calls you would like to avoid.

Comment: @andrewTobilko, Yeah, it looks like there is no option except training them.