# C++-like friend class mechanism in Java

Tags: java, friend

Do you know how can I make an object changeable only inside a special class?
In this example I want the object PrivateObject to be only changable (incrementable) inside the `Box` class, nowhere else. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
public class Box { 

    private PrivateObject prv;

    public void setPrivateObject(PrivateObject p){
        prv = p;
    }

    public void changeValue(){
        prv.increment();

    }

}


public class PrivateObject {
    private value;
    public increment(){
        value++;
    }

}

PrivateObject priv = new PrivateObject ();
Box box = new Box();
box.setPPrivateObject(priv);
box.changevalue();
priv.increment(); // I don't want it to be changeable outside the Box class!
```

In C++, I would make all the `PrivateObject` properties and methods private, and the declare the `Box` class as a friend for the `PrivateObject` class.

Comment: related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182278/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-the-c-friend-concept-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `PrivateObject` is strongly related to `Box` why not make it an inner class inside `Box`?

```
class Box { 

    public static class PrivateObject {
       private value;

       private increment(){
         value++;
       }
    }

    private PrivateObject prv;

    public void setPrivateObject(PrivateObject p){
        prv = p;
    }

    public void changeValue(){
        prv.increment();
    }       
}
```

Now you cannot call `increment` from outside `Box`:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Box.PrivateObject obj = new Box.PrivateObject();
    Box b = new Box();
    b.setPrivateObject(obj);
    obj.increment(); // not visible     
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The closest would be to make PrivateObject an inner class of Box and make `increment` private. That way, the method will be accessible only within the `Box` class.

```
public class Box {

    private PrivateObject prv;

    public void setPrivateObject(PrivateObject p) {
        prv = p;
    }

    public void changeValue() {
        prv.increment();

    }

    public static class PrivateObject {

        private int value;

        private void increment() {
            value++;
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to do that, the next option would be to make `increment` package private and locate the 2 classes in the same package. That way, only classes within that package will have access to that method. But that might include classes other than Box.

Answer (score 3):

Java does not have any language feature equivalent of C++'s friend keyword. However , there are number of application-level alternatives :

1. Declare the `increment()` method of the `PrivateObject` class as package- private and define Box in the same package.

OR

2.Let the calling code pass a token into `increment()` - inside this method check if this token is indeed coming from `Box` class and allow or disallow.

The idea is to keep the coupling between `PrivateObject` and `Box` class manageable.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, you would create a group of "friends" by putting multiple classes in the same package. Then, use default scope (no access specifier) on the classes, methods and fields you want to restrict access to.