# Better packages structure in my Android library

Tags: java, android, package, android-library

I'm writing (for the first time) an Android library (with its own Activities) that will be imported in other Android projects using Android aar package.

My goal would be to publish only one class (let's call it `MyPlugin`) that does all the stuff (calling activities etc.) offering public methods; but it seems, to me, that all Activities must be `public`; so I would like to separate classes the user wants to use from classes i don't want to be used. Something like:

```
com.mycompany.myplugin.api
 |--> MyPlugin (public class with public methods)
com.mycompany.myplugin.activities
 |--> Acitivty1
 |--> ....
 |--> ActivityN (public? activities)
com.mycompany.myplugin.mystuff
 |--> Services (protected? class with protected? methods)
```

With this design I could say to the user "You should use only api package".

The problem is the Serivice class: it's used by Activities and MyPlugin, and it should be in the same package if I want it (or its methods) to be `protected` (so the final user can't see it).

I know that with reflection the final user could do anything but I want to be as clean and simple as possible.

The only solution I found is to have just one package with all the classes, but, as I said, I would like to separate `MyPlugin` from Activities.

Comment: You could use something like friend concept: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182278/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-the-c-friend-concept-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common convention is to use a package named `internal` for private implementation/internal classes .

```
com.mycompany.myplugin // all public stuff here and in its subpackages
com.mycompany.myplugin.internal // all non public stuff
```

Also, follow [@Drew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28698962/1715004) advice:

> It's often good idea to populate your package by feature, not by component

References:

- https://wiki.eclipse.org/Naming_Conventions#Internal_Implementation_Packages
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/sLiyI6VlMZ8

Comment: internal must have some public methods otherwise could not be used by myplugin package (myplugin.internal is a different package from myplugin)

Comment: There will be lots of public classes and methods, but, by convetion, clients shall not use those as they are internal and intended to be used only by your own code.

Answer (score 2):

You can't  create non-public Android components (Activity, Service, BroadcastReceiver). Neither can their constructors be non-public.

It's often good idea to populate your package by feature, not by component: e.g.

```
|-awesomefeatureone
|----Activity1
|----Fragment1
|----AsyncTask1
|----Service1
|-awesomefeaturetwo
|----BroadcastReceiver2
|----Service2
```

In this case you may play some useful tricks with encapsulation (`package-local` visibility, `protected` stuff).

I guess you won't be able to hide your component classes from end-user. But you might prohibit running one of your components directly from client code: use approach @billmuell suggested in comment, or just use package-local extras to start the `Activity`, package-local argument extras to create `Fragment`...you got the idea.

```
public class SomeFragment extends Fragment{
    static final String ARG = "package_local_arg";
    protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
        super.onCreate(state);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if(args == null || !args.contains(ARG)){       
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }
}


public class SamePackageActivity extends Activity {

   public void doSometh(){
        Fragment f = new SomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(SomeFragment.ARG, 1);
        f.setArguments();
        ...
   }
}
```