# Encapsulate Data on Java

Tags: java, encapsulation, factory-pattern

Im building an API and i would like the following done maintaining the packages

```
com.example.objects
 -> public someObject (class)
     -> int someInt = 500;

com.example.database
 -> private database (class)
     -> void someMethod() {
          (i need access to someInt here)
        }
```

The problem comes because i need to access the constant someInt from someObject in the database methods. But at the same time i don't like outside users of the API to be able to see the value of someInt.

I can't find a way to do this without the two classes being inside the same package since (friend c++) relation doesn't exists in java and i don't want to force it since its considered a bad design in java.

Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe this can be usefull http://stackoverflow.com/a/18634125/3998458

Comment: No. That is a way of forcing friend mechanism in java. And I don't want that since it is considered a bad  programming trick by the java community