# How to design classes in this use case?

Tags: java, oop

I have three classes-A,B,C in java. Conditions-

1. A can access members of B and C
2. B can access members of C
3. C cannot access members of A and B
4. B cannot access members of A

If I declare members of B,C as protected and put all the classes in a package, I won't able to enforce the 3rd and 4th condition.
What should be the approach here?

I can see that most of the answers mentioned that I can directly do inheritance like A <- B <- C. But, lets assume we have classes like patient and doctor. So, doctor needs to know the details a patient given a patient id. Implementation wise If I extend doctor from patient, that will solve the use case. But, logically it doesn't make sense to me to extend doctor from patient as doctor is not a patient.

Comment: Looks like A extends B, and C has public members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I should have mentioned the exact use case I was thinking while writing the question. I updated my question later accordingly.
For my use case, I think aggregation is the right approach instead of inheritance as the classes has has-a relationship instead of is-a.

Answer (score 0):

You should create proper interfaces for each usecase and instead of using classes directly accept interfaces

For example it could look like

```
interface AccessibleA {
    int getA();
    void setA(int a);
    // other methods declarations - non accessors
}

interface InaccessibleA {
    // other methods declarations - non accessors
}

class A implements AccessibleA, InaccessibleA {
    private int a;

    // getter and setter

    public A(AccessibleB b, AccessibleC c) {
        // you can assign these values or use them
    }

    // other methods
}

// the same interfaces for B and C

class B implements AccessibleB, InaccessibleB {
    private int b;

    // getter and setter

    public A(InaccessibleA a, AccessibleC c) {
        // you can assign these values or use them
    }

    // other methods
}

// etc
```

Unfortunately in Java there is not "friend function" implementation ([there is something like this in C++](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_friend_functions.htm)) however there are some ways to mock this behaviour. For example read:

- [Is there a way to simulate the C++ 'friend' concept in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182278/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-the-c-friend-concept-in-java)

Just I'm not sure does it worth in your case

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
package c;
class C { 
    protected String foo;
}

package b;
class B extends C { 
    protected String bar;
}

package a;
class A extends B { 
    protected String baz;
}
```

protected fields are visible to subclasses in a different package, default (package-private) fields are only visible to subclasses in the same package.

See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use inheritence here.
If C is the parent most class, B can inherit C, and A can inherit B.
So in this scenerio, A can access his parent B and parent's parent C, B can access his parent C, While C cannot access A or B. and B cannot access A as B is the parent class of A.